# Unable to use knife command on Chef workstation

Tags: chef-infra, devops, chef-windows, chef-workstation

I want to use `knife` command on `chef` workstation. But unable to use it now. I deleted my one account using which, I was using knife command but I am getting this error

```
ERROR: You authenticated successfully to https:<chef_server_url> as <user> but user not present in Organisation
Response:  User not registered in the organisation
```

I searched a lot on the web but could not come up with a solution

```
cd C:/chef-repo
knife node list
```

This is showing error

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your user to your organization, so the user will be a part of organization. This needs to be done on your chef-server, by using command:

```
chef-server-ctl org-user-add ORG_NAME USER_NAME
```

Where `ORG_NAME` is name of the organization that you have configured on chef-server and `USER_NAME` is your Chef username.

source: https://docs.chef.io/server_users.html